# sed replace second last line of file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to replace second last line of file, I know $ use for last line but don't know how to say second line from end.

```
parallel (
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
build( "Build2Test", BUILDFILE: "", WARFILE: "http://maven.example.com/130602.0.war", STUDY: "UK", BUG: "33323" )
}},
)
```

I want to replace `}},` with `}}`  in short i want to remove `,` comma  but this file has many other codes so i can't use pattern match i need to use second line from end of file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work (note that on some systems you may need to remove all of the comments):

```
sed '1 {        # if this is the first line
  h               # copy to hold space
  d               # delete pattern space and return to start
}
/^}},$/ {       # if this line matches regex /^}},$/
  x               # exchange pattern and hold space
  b               # print pattern space and return to start
}
H               # append line to hold space
$ {             # if this is the last line
  x               # exchange pattern and hold space
  s/^}},/}}/      # replace "}}," at start of pattern space with "}}"
  b               # print pattern space and return to start
}
d               # delete pattern space and return to start'
```

Or the compact version:

```
sed '1{h;d};/^}},$/{x;b};H;${x;s/^}},/}}/;b};d'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'parallel (
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
build( "Build2Test", BUILDFILE: "", WARFILE: "http://maven.example.com/130602.0.war", STUDY: "UK", BUG: "33323" )
}},
)' | sed '1{h;d};/^}},$/{x;b};H;${x;s/^}},/}}/;b};d'
parallel (
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
build( "Build2Test", BUILDFILE: "", WARFILE: "http://maven.example.com/130602.0.war", STUDY: "UK", BUG: "33323" )
}}
)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you know, how to change N-th line, simply reverse the the file first, e.g. It is not as much professional as the other sed solutions, but works... :)

```
tail -r <file | sed '2s/}},/}}/' | tail -r >newfile
```

e.g. from the next input

```
}},
}},
}},
}},
}},
```

the above makes

```
}},
}},
}},
}}
}},
```

The `tail -r` are BSD equivalent of Linux's `tac` command. On Linux use `tac` on OS X or Freebsd use `tail -r`. Bot doing the same: prints the file in reveresed order of lines (last line prints as first).

Answer (score 6):

reverse the file, work on the 2nd line, then re-reverse the file:

```
tac file | sed '2 s/,$//' | tac
```

to save the result back to "file", add this to the command

```
 > file.new && mv file file.bak && mv file.new file
```

Or, use an [`ed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) script

```
ed file <<END
$-1 s/,$//
w
q
END
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;$s/}},/}}/;P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and at-end-of-file substitute the required pattern.